# Display Dictionaries in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I am written a simple Tkinter program and i am trying to display both my stock name and stock Quantity, but i find that only my stock name displays. My code is as follows:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from datetime import datetime
now= datetime.now()
x = []
d = dict()
def quit():
    print("Have a great day! Goodbye :)")
    sys.exit(0)
def display():
    x_var.set(list(d))
def add(*args): 
    global stock
    global d
    global Quantity
    stock = stock_Entry.get()
    Quantity = int(Quantity_Entry.get())
    if stock not in d:
        d[stock] = Quantity
    else:
        d[stock] += Quantity

root = Tk()
root.title("Homework 5 216020088")

x_var = StringVar()
x_var.set(x)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="6 6 20 20")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="you are accesing this on day %s of month %s of %s" % (now.day,now.month,now.year)+" at exactly %s:%s:%s" % (now.hour,now.minute,now.second), foreground="yellow", background="Black").grid(column=0, row = 0)

stock_Entry= ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 60, textvariable="stock")
stock_Entry.grid(column=0, row = 1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the stock name").grid(column=1, row = 1, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

Quantity_Entry= ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 60, textvariable="Quantity")
Quantity_Entry.grid(column=0, row = 2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the quantity").grid(column=1, row = 2, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Add", command=add).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Display", command=display).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=S)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Exit", command=quit).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=E)

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable= x_var).grid(column=0, row= 4, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Now, this is only displaying my stock and not the Quantity, can you please help me or recommend what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in your `display()` function you are only changing `x_var` which refers to the stock.
Have you tried adding another `tk.Label` and bind a quantity variable to it?

Comment: Yes i have but still nothing, could you show me how

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
x = []
d = {}


def quit():
    print("Have a great day! Goodbye :)")
    sys.exit(0)


def display():
    x = []
    for key, value in d.items():
        x.append([key, value])
    print(x)
    x_var.set(x)



def add(*args):
    global stock
    global d
    global Quantity
    stock = stock_Entry.get()
    Quantity = int(Quantity_Entry.get())
    if stock not in d:
        d[stock] = Quantity
    else:
        d[stock] += Quantity


root = Tk()
root.title("Homework 5 216020088")

x_var = StringVar()
x_var.set(x)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="6 6 20 20")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="you are accesing this on day %s of month %s of %s" % (
now.day, now.month, now.year) + " at exactly %s:%s:%s" % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second), foreground="yellow",
          background="Black").grid(column=0, row=0)

stock_Entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=60, textvariable="stock")
stock_Entry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the stock name").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

Quantity_Entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=60, textvariable="Quantity")
Quantity_Entry.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the quantity").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Add", command=add).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Display", command=display).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=S)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Exit", command=quit).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=E)

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=x_var).grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```